# Recursion : How do I return value-1 from recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I wrote a method to return the height of a Binary Search Tree.

Now I am trying to return `height - 1` from the recursive method. I am doing this by adding extra `if` conditions.

Is there a better way to return the `value - 1` from the recursive function?

```
static int height(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {       
        return 0;
    }

    if (root.left == null && root.right==null) {      
        return 1;            
    } else
        // I want to return height - 1.
        // For example if max height is 10, I wanted to return 9.
        return (1 + Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right));   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your base cases return -1 and 0 respectively:

```
static int height(Node root) {
    if(root == null)       
        return -1;
    if(root.left == null && root.right==null)      
        return 0;            
    else
        return 1+ Math.max(height(root.left),
                   height(root.right));   
}
```

Update to comply with requirement mentioned in comment: "What if I wanted to return 0 for null node, 1 for single node and if height-1 for all other."

```
static int funny_height(Node root) {
    int h = height(node);
    return h <= 0 ? h + 1 : h;
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to return 0 for null node, 1 for single node and height-1 for all other.
For Ex:For a BST with 7 elements {3,2,1,5,4,6,7} the methid should return  3 instead of 4

Comment: This is somewhat inconsistent since it gives 1 for several different trees. But if you really want that, see the update.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make sure that we have to use another function to achieve this and this is not possible with recursion. Do you think we can achieve this using the same recursive function?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy and understandable way to do it in just one recursive function. This may be another hint that the requirement is somewhat flawed.

Comment: I was just trying to find out if this is possible. I don't have any requirement this is out of curiosity. Thanks for your inputs.